# Hosting python SimpleHTTPServer in /root gives scary output!

Tags: python, webserver

This is how I started my SimpleHTTPServer:

```
root@sanctum:~# python -m SimpleHTTPServer 80
```

This is the response that I got:

```
root@sanctum:~# curl http://localhost
{
  "ip": "37.130.227.133",
  "hostname": "torland1-this.is.a.tor.exit.server.torland.is",
  "city": "",
  "region": "",
  "country": "GB",
  "loc": "51.4964,-0.1224",
  "org": "AS13213 UK-2 Limited"
}
```

Anywhere else it gives (as expected) directory listing of the directory we ran the command in.

Any ideas as to why this JSON was passed?

python console:

`127.0.0.1 - - [19/Feb/2017 00:14:05] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Feb/2017 00:14:06] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Feb/2017 00:14:07] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -`

Comment: This output does not seem scary. It seems like SimpleHTTP's error response. The error, in this case, is probably permissions. /root is not globally readable.

Comment: @user535733 it was unexpected so it scared me

Comment: @user535733 working on it!

Comment: What was python's output for your request?